# problem to load swf file in android

Tags: android

> hi friends,
>   i want to load swf file in android emulator.but there is problem to display.
>   problem is when i run the project display blank white screen. here is the code ::

```
             String url ="file:///android_asset/co.swf";

             WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

             wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

             wv.loadUrl(url);
```

> is there any permission are give to manifest file?

Comment: Do you really have three slashes (///) after file: ? If so your url could be the problem.

Comment: i have try to put 2 slash in application and run it but still not get solve problem

Comment: Have a look at this: http://androidforums.com/application-development/171895-play-local-swf-file-flash-webview.html#post2267154

Comment: i have already try this but cant get success. plz tell me anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't be able to access the swf direcly from webview. So instead you have to embed the swf file in html and then call that file instead.
This both files should be placed in assets folder inside your project.

So your HTML file will look somewhat like this
File:co.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
      <object id="i1">
          <param name = "movie" value = "co.swf">
          <embed src = "file:///android_asset/co.swf" ></embed>
      </object>
      <script>
          var x = document.getElementById("i1")
          x.setAttribute("height", screen.height);
          x.setAttribute("width", screen.width);
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In Java file:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
ws.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/co.html");
```

And the main xml (activity) should contain a webview possibly with id webView1 which is automatically generated. This should work.